# SyntaxError: missing : after property id - after obfuscation

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

Obfuscated code raising error "SyntaxError: missing : after property id".

Code is checked on [lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php) and passing without any errors or warnings.

This is original code (which is also a very first line in this js document):

```
var pgetColor = {
'AB': '#CAD17D',
'BC': '#7DD1AE',
'CL': '#919AFF',
'CI': '#FFE291',
'HB': '#84DBD5',
'ON': '#AA84DB',
'PM': '#DB848A',
'SR': '#B5DB84',
'TS': '#C96B9B',
'IS': '#FFC926',
'FREE': '#5FCF68'
};
```

this is an error report:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Prettify the obfuscated code then test it with jsHint to see if it is the obfuscated code that's wrong (which means the obfuscator implementation is wrong). Just a tip: obfuscation doesn't help. It just adds to the processing. Minifying/uglifying would be better.

Comment: What tool are you using to obfuscate that code?

Comment: Yeah, that's a syntax error all right, you just can't have that `[` there. I would use a different obfuscator.

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni: http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/

Comment: Use a different one, uglify or like T.J. Crowder said the Closure compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in [the obfuscator you're using](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/). Your code

```
var pgetColor = {
'AB': '#CAD17D',
'BC': '#7DD1AE',
'CL': '#919AFF',
'CI': '#FFE291',
'HB': '#84DBD5',
'ON': '#AA84DB',
'PM': '#DB848A',
'SR': '#B5DB84',
'TS': '#C96B9B',
'IS': '#FFC926',
'FREE': '#5FCF68'
};
```

is getting turned into this (I added a line break):

```
var _0x5523=["\x41\x42","\x23\x43\x41\x44\x31\x37\x44","\x42\x43","\x23\x37\x44\x44\x31\x41\x45","\x43\x4C","\x23\x39\x31\x39\x41\x46\x46","\x43\x49","\x23\x46\x46\x45\x32\x39\x31","\x48\x42","\x23\x38\x34\x44\x42\x44\x35","\x4F\x4E","\x23\x41\x41\x38\x34\x44\x42","\x50\x4D","\x23\x44\x42\x38\x34\x38\x41","\x53\x52","\x23\x42\x35\x44\x42\x38\x34","\x54\x53","\x23\x43\x39\x36\x42\x39\x42","\x49\x53","\x23\x46\x46\x43\x39\x32\x36","\x46\x52\x45\x45","\x23\x35\x46\x43\x46\x36\x38"];
var pgetColor={_0x5523[0]:_0x5523[1],_0x5523[2]:_0x5523[3],_0x5523[4]:_0x5523[5],_0x5523[6]:_0x5523[7],_0x5523[8]:_0x5523[9],_0x5523[10]:_0x5523[11],_0x5523[12]:_0x5523[13],_0x5523[14]:_0x5523[15],_0x5523[16]:_0x5523[17],_0x5523[18]:_0x5523[19],_0x5523[20]:_0x5523[21]};
// ------------^^^^^^^^^^
//             This is wrong (as are the ones that follow)
```

It's invalid to have `_0x5523[0]` as the property name in the object initializer. You seem to have confused it by using string literals rather than property name literals on the left-hand side of the `:` — it's being overzealous with its string substitution. (See below if you didn't quite understand what I meant by "string literal" vs. "property name literal".) Since what you're doing is perfectly correct and reasonable, it's a bug in the obfuscator.

I would use a different obfuscator, or better yet, a compiler like the [Closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/).

If I change your code to use property name literals instead:

```
var pgetColor = {
AB: '#CAD17D',
BC: '#7DD1AE',
CL: '#919AFF',
CI: '#FFE291',
HB: '#84DBD5',
ON: '#AA84DB',
PM: '#DB848A',
SR: '#B5DB84',
TS: '#C96B9B',
IS: '#FFC926',
FREE: '#5FCF68'
};
```

...the result is fine:

```
var _0x8d33=["\x23\x43\x41\x44\x31\x37\x44","\x23\x37\x44\x44\x31\x41\x45","\x23\x39\x31\x39\x41\x46\x46","\x23\x46\x46\x45\x32\x39\x31","\x23\x38\x34\x44\x42\x44\x35","\x23\x41\x41\x38\x34\x44\x42","\x23\x44\x42\x38\x34\x38\x41","\x23\x42\x35\x44\x42\x38\x34","\x23\x43\x39\x36\x42\x39\x42","\x23\x46\x46\x43\x39\x32\x36","\x23\x35\x46\x43\x46\x36\x38"];
var pgetColor={AB:_0x8d33[0],BC:_0x8d33[1],CL:_0x8d33[2],CI:_0x8d33[3],HB:_0x8d33[4],ON:_0x8d33[5],PM:_0x8d33[6],SR:_0x8d33[7],TS:_0x8d33[8],IS:_0x8d33[9],FREE:_0x8d33[10]};
```

But there are times when you really *want* to use string literals for the property names (for instance, if the property name has a space in it, or is a reserved word).

Comment: @dllhell: No worries, glad that helped! (You might want to drop them a bug report, your question and this answer have all the info they should need...)